# How to install customer node.js binary module globally?

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

So I've made my own module with C++ and node-gyp. Things go fine after `node-gyp configure build` and I've got under `build/Release` everything I need.

Now, in my other project where I'm using this module, I don't want to add it like

```
var a = require('../../mylib/build/Release/mylib');
```

but instead

```
var a = require('mylib');
```

after defining dependencies in `package.json`. So how do I use npm or something else to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the entry point to your package to the `main` field in your package.json. This is what will be called when you do `require('yourpackage')`.

See these links:

1. at end of section 8.1 http://book.mixu.net/node/ch8.html
2. under section `main` in https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html

Answer (score 0):

`sudo npm install --global /home/nhaa123/mylib/build/Release/mylib` (if that is the folder containing your package.json) documentation: https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to install the module globally – project dependencies are meant to be installed locally (in the project's folder).  The only thing you install globally are npm modules meant to be run from the command line.

Instead, just add the path to the folder containing your module (assuming it has its own package.json) to your project's package.json.

```
{
    "name": "My Project",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.1.x",
        "mylib": "/home/me/mylib"
    }
}
```